# Counting registers/thread in Cuda kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu-registers, hpc

The nSight profiler tells me that the following kernel uses 52 registers per thread:

```
 //Just the first lines of the kernel.
__global__ void voles_kernel(float *params, int *ctrl_params, 
                             float dt, float currTime,
                             float *dev_voles, float *dev_weasels, 
                             curandStateMtgp32 *state) 
{

 __shared__ float dev_params[9];

 __shared__ int BuYeSimStep[4];

 if(threadIdx.x < 4)
 {
   BuYeSimStep[threadIdx.x] = ctrl_params[threadIdx.x];
 }

 if(threadIdx.x < 9){
     dev_params[threadIdx.x] = params[threadIdx.x];
 }

 __syncthreads();

float currVole = curand_uniform(&state[blockIdx.x]) + 3.0;
float currWeas = curand_uniform(&state[blockIdx.x]) + 0.1;
float oldVole = currVole;
float oldWeas = currWeas;

int jj;

if (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x < BuYeSimStep[2])
{
int dayIndex = 0;

/* Not declaring any new variable from here on, just doing arithmetics.
   ....... */
```

If each register has 4 bytes I don't understand how we get to 52 registers, even
assuming that the arrays params[9] and ctrl_params[4] end up in registers (in which
case using shared memory as I did doesn't make sense). I would
like to increase occupancy, but I don't get why I'm using so many registers.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's generally difficult to look at C code and predict the register usage from it.  The compiler may aggressively optimize code by increasing register usage, perhaps to save an instruction here or there.   You seem to be making an assumption that register usage can be predicted from your C code variable allocations, and while there is some connection between the two, you cannot assume register usage can be computed directly from C code variable allocations.

Since you haven't provided your code, nobody can actually help with the register usage.  If you want to better understand the register usage, you will need to look at the PTX code directly.  To do this, compile your code using `nvcc` with the `-ptx` switch, and inspect the resultant .ptx file directly.  To do this you may wish to refer to the [PTX documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) as well as the [nvcc documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) to look at the various compiler options.

You haven't provided your code, so it's not really possible to make any direct suggestions, but you may be able to reduce register usage by reducing constant usage, reducing or refactoring arithmetic usage, switching from `double` to `float`, and I'm sure there are many other suggestions as well.  Register usage will also be affected if you are passing the `-G` switch to the compiler.

You can limit the compiler's usage of registers per thread by passing the `-maxrregcount` switch to `nvcc` with an appropriate parameter, such as `-maxrregcount 20` which will instruct the compiler to limit itself to 20 registers per thread.  This tactic may not give good results, however, or you may need to tune the parameter to a value which doesn't sacrifice too much performance.    However you may find an optimum choice which doesn't sacrifice too much basic performance but allows you to improve occupancy.  If you constrain the compiler too much, it will begin to spill it's needed register usage to local memory, which will generally reduce performance.

You should also be aware that you can pass `-Xptxas -v` to `nvcc` which will give useful output about the compiler's register usage and other related data (spilling, etc.) at compile time.

Comment: -maxregcount is not the recommend approach as it sets the value for all functions in the compilation unit. You should use [____launch_bounds____](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) attribute. Reviewing PTX tends to be useless unless you are writing in PTX. You can review the SASS code using cuobjdump, nvdisasm, or the development tools. The total register count can be found for grep r[0-9]+ and finding the highest match. The total register count will be at most 3 higher if the highest register was use for a 128 (vec4) operation.

Comment: The runtime register allocation per thread may be higher than the value reported by the compiler due to (a) ABI compliance, or (b) due to register allocation granularity per thread. The register allocation granularity per thread is 8 on kepler devices and 2 or 4 on Fermi.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the occupancy, a direct way is using compiler flag: maxregcount to restrict the usage of registers, but it may suffer a performance loss because some registers will be spilled to local memory, which is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you debug your code with Eclipse Nsight.
Create a breakpoint at the first line of your kernel and step to there.
In Debug Perspective, inside the CUDA Thread, you have the current stack trace. Right-click on the stack and click on "Instruction Stepping Mode". The window "Disassembly" will open your kernel PTX Assembly. You can continue stepping in your kernel to track the correlation of your source code and the assembly. So you can discover which register is used for.